# Connect to site with unknown scheme via Guzzle

Tags: php, curl, guzzle6, guzzle

I have a list of URL without scheme specified, ex.:

- github.com (works only with `https`);
- what.ever (works only with `http`);
- google.com (supports both schemes).

I need to get contents of its' root path (`/`) using Guzzle (v6), but I do not know their scheme: `http` or `https`.

Can I solve my task without making 2 requests?

Comment: Only if the site automatically redirects you and you configure Guzzle to follow redirects.

Answer (score 0):

Guzzle will follow redirects by default, so unless you have an explicit list of URL's that are https then I would prepend http if missing and allow the website to redirect if it only accepts https requests (which is what they should do).

```
<?php

require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use GuzzleHttp\Client;

$response = (new Client)->get('http://github.com/', ['debug' => true]);
```

Response:

```
> GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: github.com
User-Agent: GuzzleHttp/6.2.1 curl/7.51.0 PHP/5.6.30

< HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
< Content-length: 0
< Location: https://github.com/
< Connection: close
<
* Curl_http_done: called premature == 0
* Closing connection 0
*   Trying 192.30.253.112...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to github.com (192.30.253.112) port 443 (#1)
* TLS 1.2 connection using TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
* Server certificate: github.com
* Server certificate: DigiCert SHA2 Extended Validation Server CA
* Server certificate: DigiCert High Assurance EV Root CA
> GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: github.com
User-Agent: GuzzleHttp/6.2.1 curl/7.51.0 PHP/5.6.30

< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Server: GitHub.com
< Date: Wed, 31 May 2017 15:46:59 GMT
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Status: 200 OK
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally — no, you cannot solve the problem without two requests (because one there might be no redirect).

You can do 2 async requests with Guzzle, then you will spend probably the same time, but with a proper general solution.

Just create two requests and wait for both:

```
 $httpResponsePromise = $client->getAsync('http://' . $url);
 $httpsResponsePromise = $client->getAsync('https://' . $url);

 list($httpResponse, $httpsResponse) = \GuzzleHttp\Promise\all(
     [$httpResponsePromise, $httpsResponsePromise]
 );
```

That's all, now you have two responses (for each protocol) and you make them in parallel.